# Angular/ng-bootstrap - Change Progressbar with current slide

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

My intention is to change the progress bar's width with every slide. I'm currently using the progress bar given by bootstrap. So far I'm calling an event in HTML with every slide. This event fetches this information about the slide:

```
Console:
{prev: "ngb-slide-0", current: "ngb-slide-1", direction: "left"}
```

The progress bar fetches its information regarding the width from currentSlide (app.component.ts), which works fine:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [style.width.%]="currentSlide"></div>
  </div>
```

Typescript progression so far:

```
export class AppComponent {

  public currentSlide: number;

  images = ['assets/images/image1.jpg', 'assets/images/image2.jpg', 'assets/images/image3.jpg'];

  changeProgress(slide: any): void {
    console.log(slide);
  }
}
```

My solution path in words:

```
if current: ngb-slide-0 then currentSlide = 33,33
if current: ngb-slide-1 then currentSlide = 66,66 
if current: ngb-slide-2 then currentSlide = 100
```

**How to transform these words into code?**
Thanks in advance, Tim 


Rest of html (Slider example):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" (slide)="changeProgress($event)">
        <ng-template ngbSlide>
          <img [src]="images[0]" alt="First slide">
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbSlide>
          <img [src]="images[1]" alt="Second slide">
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbSlide>
          <img [src]="images[2]" alt="Third slide">
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-carousel>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you create a quick example on https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: @chiril.sarajiu Sorry, took me a while to figure out how to insert ng-bootstrap on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-demo-hiufwv?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable that holds the current percentage of the progress in the slides and change that value when you fire the changeProgress method and bind that percentage to your progress bar like so :

```
<div class="progress-bar active" role="progressbar" [style.width.%]="currentPercentage"
             [attr.aria-valuenow]="currentPercentage" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{this.currentPercentage}}%</div>
```

and in your component it should look something like this

```
export class AppComponent {

  public currentSlide: number;
  public currentPercentage: number;

  images = ['assets/images/image1.jpg', 'assets/images/image2.jpg', 'assets/images/image3.jpg'];

  changeProgress(event: any): void {
    this.currentSlide = Number(event.current.substring(10));//10 because you want to remove the string 'ngb-slide-' and get only the selected image
    this.currentPercentage = this.currentSlide / this.images.length * 100;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! and like so you can in the future add more images to your slide show and have a dynamic code ( i would suggest using a ng-For to display all  ng-templates of your carrousel)

Comment: The slide ID doesn't always start at 0 or 1. It can start as **ngb-slide-8**

Comment: Works for my purposes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
// Add the caroussel to you component class, so you can access the slides array
@ViewChild(NgbCarousel) ngbCarousel;

....

changeProgress(slide: any): void {
    // Find the current slide index.
    let slideIndex = this.ngbCarousel.slides._results.findIndex( elem => {
      return elem.id == slide.current;
    });

    // Convert it to a percentage
    this.currentPercentage = (slideIndex + 1) / this.images.length * 100;
}
```